# Google App Script - Make numeric entries 0 if conditions in another column match

Tags: google-apps-script

I`m trying to automate an action that does the below..

Make numeric value to zero, if the entry in column next to this numeric value satisfies.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ipo716-K17BUn6RzS2AQqSaC41eSqAEKux-nckeir9Q/edit?usp=sharing

Above is the link to the sample data i`m referring to

Basically, if column A, "events" contains "do not count", I want to make those conversions to "0"

So the right total conversions there will be 80

is there way to do this efficiently through Google App Script?

Below is what I tried

```
function testing(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues()

  for (n=0; n<data.length;++n){
    if(data[n][0].toString().match('Retargeting - do not count') == 0){
      data[n][2] = 0
    }
    else if(data[n][0].toString().match('Step 3 pool size - do not count') == 0){
      data[n][2] = 0
    }
    else if(data[n][0].toString().match('Step 2 Retargeting - do not count') == 0){
      data[n][2] = 0
    }
  }

  Logger.log(data)

  sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[2].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to check `contains "do not count"`, then you don't need separate conditions for each type of text.

The other change is that if there is no match, the result is `null`, not `0`.

So inside the for loop, you could try:

```
if(data[n][0].toString().match('do not count') != null){
  data[n][2] = 0;
}
```

Comment: This works a treat, you could also use `.indexOf('do not count') > -1)` to achieve the same output. You'll need to set `data[n][1]` rather than `data[n][2]` to set column B.